# Python global variable not working for reading two files

Tags: python-2.7, csv, global-variables

I am trying to read 2 `.csv` files of following format

```
a,23
b,44
c,5
d,0
line1
line2
.... line 43
```

So, in above `b,44` says that after `d,0`, we have 44 lines of same testing. So we need to generate some output from those 44 lines. But these 44 might not be in the same file and may be in the second .csv file (might be split).

That's why I want to store `b,44` value globally so that I can use it in the parsing of next file.

Answer (score 0):

this can handle this case specifically, as i understood from the post you want to get the number after the "b," and the b,number thing is a part of your format in your header.

```
sheet = open('New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.csv', 'r')
    lister = sheet.read()


    mynum = lister.split('b')
    mynum=mynum[1].strip(',')
    mynum = mynum.split('\n')
    mynum=int(mynum[0])
```

Comment: That is not what i want, I want to store that 44 value globally so that i can use that value while parsing next csv file. I have 2 csv in which rows are split and i want to parse both file to get the whole data and them do some operation on that